# Attach to process IIS not hitting breakpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

When I attach Visual Studio to my Asp.Core MVC App running in IIS, the Breakpoints will not get hit. I checked the IIS folder where I put my files in and there are the needed .pdb files inside. The files are created via the publish command in VS.

[image]

I don't know what you need me to share here, so sorry for that few information.

Comment: Did you publish as Debug instead of Release?

Comment: Yes, I published it with Debug set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean full IIS and not IIS Express.

Check your 'Web' settings in the Project Properties in Visual Studio. You are looking for three things:

1. "Local IIS" is selected from the drop down.
2. The 'Project Url' is accurate (should match the URL you use to access the site). If it's wrong, that will cause the problem you are experiencing (I speak from experience).
3. "ASP.NET" is selected under 'Debuggers'.

Look here for instructions, including a screenshot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2017#debug-aspnet-apps

Comment: Still no success, I followed the instructions on your provided microsoft site and checked I do all correct, but my breakpoints never get hit

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the solution. I always attached to w3wp.exe, but I needed to attach to dotnet.exe

Comment: Oh, you are manually attaching to the process. Any reason for that? With the setup I described, it would be automatic when you start debugging.

Comment: This was the solution for me -- my environment had IIS Express selected instead of Local IIS.

Answer (score 8):

My favorite trick for debugging IIS / IIS Express locally is to add a little bit of code.

Somewhere in Global.asax.cs

```
public static void Application_Initialize() {
 AttachDebugger();
...
}

[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
private void AttachDebugger() {
  if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached()) {
     System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
  }
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

Comment: Man... Thank you!

Comment: NP.  Please don't forget to (up)vote.  I still use this in asp.net core and azure function local debugging too.

Comment: This works in .net core and .net 5 too.  I just added it to another new site I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please make sure the debug attribute is true in web.config file.

If the debugger doesn’t load the .pdb file, the Breakpiont cannot be hit. So please make sure that the symbols are loaded by the debugger. We can check if the debugger loads this pdb file by the following steps (Debug->Windows->Modules), and then select your dll module to see if the pdb file is loaded. If the pdb file is not loaded, we can load it manually (Right click the dll model->Select Load Symbols).

Comment: I do not have a web.config. Also there is no Gorilla.WebApi.dll file inside the Modules Window

Comment: We can follow this steps
We can check if the debugger loads this pdb file by the following steps (Debug->Windows->Modules), and then select your dll module to see if the pdb file is loaded. If the pdb file is not loaded, we can load it manually (Right click the dll model->Select Load Symbols).

Comment: But there are only System32 .dll Files, so I am not able to load the symbols for my projects

Comment: Try This 
Debug -> Delete All Breakpoints ( http://darrinbishop.com/blog/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-hangs-after-visual-studio-2010-f5-debugging ) After that you can use them again, but do it once. It will remove some kind of "invalid" breakpoints too and then loading symbols will be fast again

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your Project Url is typed properly. In my case the folder name was missing after host name i.e http://localhost/**webApplication**,
this has resulted in that the Breakpoints will not get hit.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VInwc.png)